# setting an image vertically aligned with text

Tags: html, css

> EDIT: Please disregard the phone/email row.

I would like to reach this kind of result:

[image]

Since I need the side texts to be as the same height of the icon, I am having some issues with the relative and absolute div wrappers and how to set them right.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row topWrapper">
    <div class="iconWrapper">
        <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="captionWrapper">
        <h5><strong>Liat </strong></h5>
        <h5>Your recruitment counsel</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.topWrapper {
  background-color: #d9534f;
  height: 150px;
  .iconWrapper {
    background-color: #f7ecb5;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width:16.67%;
    i{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      @include translate(0, -50%);
    }
  }
  .captionWrapper{
    background-color: #245580;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use absolute position to get what you want, just a few things and you are good to go.

See code snippet:

> **Note**: i didn't use **SCSS** for demonstration purpose

```css
.topWrapper {
  background-color: #d9534f;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.iconWrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.captionWrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

.captionWrapper h5 {
  margin: 2px;
  /*reduce the margin to make the two texts aligned with the icon*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row topWrapper">
  <div class="iconWrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="captionWrapper">
    <h5><strong>Liat </strong></h5>
    <h5>Your recruitment counsel</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```